# How to rename "Publish" metabox title in post screen

Tags: posts, functions, metabox, publish

I've looked everywhere trying to find how to **rename** the "Publish" metabox title in the WordPress backend post screen. There's help for every other metabox for changing titles and there's help for changing everything but the title for the Publish metabox.

I'm sure it's simple but I'm just not getting close.

Comment: Please revisit your previous questions after reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Comment: I'm not following?

Comment: Gotcha :) Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to remove the meta box and then add it back in with your new title:

```
function change_publish_meta_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'post', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'YOUR TITLE HERE', 'post_submit_meta_box', null, 'side', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post',  'change_publish_meta_box' );
```

(Change `YOUR TITLE HERE` to whatever you want)

Comment: The metabox isn't showing

Comment: Edited and confirmed it works now. Had to change the priority from "core" to "high".